# Is it better to use Vuex modules, or have multiple stores?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm new to Vue, and using it to build a SPA (Vue v3). I'm using the VueX library to store global application state.

To try to keep my store clean (as it will grow unmanageable as the application gets bigger), I'm using modules, as [explained on the Vuex website](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html). But it seems like this feature requires a lot of extra boilerplate: I have to go through the root store to get to my modules (which makes me wonder what the point is: why is `store.moduleA.moduleB.state.val` better than `store.state.A.B.val`?).

Is it possible to have multiple independent Vuex stores in my application, instead of a single root store with modules? If so, why wouldn't I do this (allowing more direct access to my data), instead of using a single store with modules?

Comment: Your examples don't make sense - why would `moduleB` be nested under `moduleA`? Additionally, if you use getters to access the module data then the 'depth' is  abstracted away.

Comment: >"why wouldn't I do this"
Because the data should be accessible to each other using an event system? Are we looking for multiple global states that don't have to talk or know each other's data? If not then one store with modules is probably the best way.

Comment: @match Nesting is one of the use-cases of modules. Also, your suggestion of using getters seems even worse - like now I have to add extra boilerplate to make accessing my state less onerous...

Comment: @Kunukn I could see how it would be necessary if two-way access was needed - i.e. if stateA needs to access stateB and vice-versa. However, if the access is one-way (or not at all) then I don't see why they need to be together. (And if two-way access is needed, then it would probably be a good idea to merge them into a single state, no?)

Comment: It probably depends on your use case. I don't think you can have multiple Vuex stores. It seems not to be designed for that.
Vuex is not about one or two-way data-binding. It is an event system. Anyone can dispatch events. The event-receivers act on it, do possible side-effects and update the state (the store). With Vue 3 and composition API, it is possible to have multiple "custom-build" stores. Maybe this link could be an inspiration https://dev.to/vuesomedev/you-might-not-need-vuex-with-vue-3-52e4

Comment: Yes, I was more meaning what is your purpose in using nested modules here? Ultimately modules are about compartmentalisation and separation of concerns. Additionally getters/mutations/actions exist to provide safe and flexible ways to modify state. If you don't need those then just use a global object or event bus.

Comment: @match For now, my state has 3 modules: shopping cart, user info, and dynamically-loaded configuration. I need to store stuff, to access it, and to subscribe to updates when something changes. Something as basic as subscribing to events requires immediate boilerplate - there's only one subscribe method and it catches ALL mutations. Then I have to add boilerplate to wade through the tree to get to my data. I just can't see how this wouldn't be a huge PITA in a large application.